# show row based on other row criteria

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am looking to show certain rows in sql table called parts based on a later row entry.
See the list below. I want to show rows that dont have a class 0 in a later row for each specific model and part.

```
Log | SourceTime| Class| model | part
----+-----------+------+-------+-----
614 | 14:14     | 0    | FORD  | right wing 
613 | 14:13     | 1    | FORD  | right wing
612 | 14:12     | 1    | TOYOTA| left wing
611 | 14:11     | 0    | TOYOTA| right wing 
610 | 14:10     | 1    | TOYOTA| right wing 
609 | 14:09     | 0    | OPEL  | right lamp
608 | 14:08     | 1    | OPEL  | right lamp
607 | 14:07     | 1    | OPEL  | back right wheel 
606 | 14:06     | 0    | FORD  | right wheel
605 | 14:05     | 1    | FORD  | right wheel
```

these 2 rows should be showing

```
612 | 14:12     | 1    | TOYOTA| left wing
607 | 14:07     | 1    | OPEL  | back right wheel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:** Multiple CTE on same table may solve your problem

```
WITH t1 AS(

         SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LOG ORDER BY LOG) RN
         FROM TableName
),
t2 AS(

         SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LOG ORDER BY LOG) RN
         FROM TableName
)
SELECT t1.*
FROM t1
WHERE Class <>  0 AND
      NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                   FROM t2 
                   WHERE t1.Model=t2.Model AND 
                         t2.Class = 0 AND 
                         t2.RN > t1.RN )
```

Comment: its giving me an error at the SELECT t1.* line saying "The column prefix' t1' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query"

Comment: Updated Ans. There is extra un necessary ` ,`

Comment: its giving error on t1.Model=t2.Model.. it says  t2.Model "The mulit-part identifier 't2.Model' could not be bound. Same for t2.Class and t2.RN

Comment: Have you tried exact script since I am pretty much sure about above syntax

Comment: cool. i had to order by logID desc. how would i modify it to only look in the last 200 rows in table?